# Running server using Flask brings up different project

Tags: python, html, flask

Somewhat new to flask and only have created one "Forex Converter" project. I am starting a new project called "blogly" and created an app.py and HTML files. The HTML templates folder and app.py file are located  within the same folder "flask-blogly" which is also the directory where I run my flask server using Git-Bash. The issue is when I start the server and go to the URL, my old Forex project shows on the webpage with all of the links and calculations working.

I am certain I am starting the server in the correct "flask-blogly" directory where the app.py and templates folder are. I am pretty sure My old Forex Converter project was created using a virtual environment also but cannot remember. I have tried running the server in a virtual environment and not in one, and still pulls up the old Forex project (I'm assuming venv's don't matter with starting servers?). I bet I am missing some fundamental flask concept, but any help is appreciated.

My Git-Bash commands:

```
olms2@LAPTOP-O3KD6RL5 MINGW64 ~/OneDrive/Desktop/Coding/Springboard/Current VS Code Projects
$ ls
flask-1/  flask-blogly/  git_projects/

olms2@LAPTOP-O3KD6RL5 MINGW64 ~/OneDrive/Desktop/Coding/Springboard/Current VS Code Projects
$ cd flask-blogly

olms2@LAPTOP-O3KD6RL5 MINGW64 ~/OneDrive/Desktop/Coding/Springboard/Current VS Code Projects/flask-blogly
$ ls
__pycache__/  app.py  models.py  templates/  venv/

olms2@LAPTOP-O3KD6RL5 MINGW64 ~/OneDrive/Desktop/Coding/Springboard/Current VS Code Projects/flask-blogly
$ FLASK_ENV=development flask run
 * Environment: development
 * Debug mode: on
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 201-227-015
 * Running on http:/123456789/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

My app.py contains:

```
"""Blogly application."""
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, redirect, flash, session
from flask_debugtoolbar import DebugToolbarExtension
from models import db, connect_db

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql:///blogly'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_ECHO'] = True
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = "secretkey"

connect_db(app)
db.create_all()

@app.route('/')
def home():
    """ Show home page """
    return render_template('all_users.html')
```

My base.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>User</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
    <section>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios@0.19.0/dist/axios.js"></script>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

My all_users.html:

```
    <!-- List of all users page -->
    {% extends "base.html" %}
    
   {% block content %}
    <h1>Users</h1>
    
    
    
    {% endblock %}
```

Comment: did you try to clear browser's cache? sometimes it keeps showing older pages (urls) even after you change them in your flask app

Comment: @AnaSKayed I tried that just now and the old project is still showing :(

Comment: In all_users.html, you wrote {% endblock %} without opening the block first, can you fix this and try again? Just add {% block content %} before <h1>..</h1>

Comment: @AnaSKayed Thank you for that catch! I just added it. Still same results as of now

Comment: Please follow these steps to debug. First, in app.py, try to change the return to string, not html page, I mean `return "hello world!"`. Now when you visit the link you should see this message, if this is the case, so the problem with the html not flask app.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, but the webpage still appears to be my old project. and not the "hello, world!" text. no clue what is going on! The folder that I start the server in should only use the HTML/Python files that are within the folder, correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222894/discussion-between-anas-kayed-and-anup-and-comer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After ending the server and restarting my computer, I am able to run my server with a different project.